# Regarding configuration of Nvidia GeForce GT 740M graphics driver for Toshiba Satellite P50-AX3110 in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nvidia-optimus

I have a Toshiba Satellite  P50-AX3110 laptop which comes with preinstalled Windows 8 operating system having the following configuration: 4GB RAM, 3rd generation Intel Core i5 processor, 2GB Nvidia GeForce GT 740M with Optimus graphics card.

I have recently installed Ubuntu 13.10 alongside Windows 8 in my laptop. Everything is working fine in Ubuntu 13.10 except the 2GB Nvidia GeForce GT 740M with Optimus graphics card. In the device information in Ubuntu 13.10, when I select
graphics it shows Intel Ivy Bridge, whereas it should show the Nvidia graphics card.

I have tried searching for a solution on many websites on the internet, but nothing worked. Please provide me the steps on how to configure 2GB Nvidia GeForce GT 740M with Optimus graphics card in Ubuntu 13.10 or suggest me any other version of Ubuntu which would support 2GB Nvidia GeForce GT 740M with Optimus graphics card.

One of the solutions I have tried (after searching on the internet) is that I had installed nvidia-331 package along with the bumblebee package from the Synaptic Package Manager, but still the problem persists. Kindly provide me with a solution to the above.

Answer (score 1):

Intel *bridge is the codename for the Intel embedded Graphic Chips.
So you're using the embedded chip instead of your Nvidia.

You need the Nvidia Linux driver for your Graphics Card. To get it, go to the [Nvidia website](http://www.nvidia.com), select your country, go to the support section, hit "download drivers" and enter your hardware specs.

Assuming you're running a x64 system (4GiB of RAM) this driver might be best for your system: [LINUX X64 (AMD64/EM64T) DISPLAY DRIVER](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/69372/en-us)